# How to aggregate Postgres table so that ID is unique and column values are collected in array?

Tags: postgresql

I'm not sure how to call what I'm trying to do, so trying to look it up didn't work very well. I would like to aggregate my table based on one column and have all the rows from another column collapsed into an array by unique ID.

```
| ID | some_other_value |
-------------------------
| 1  | A                |
| 1  | B                |
| 2  | C                |
| .. | ...              |
```

To return

```
| ID | values_array     |
-------------------------
| 1  | {A, B}           |
| 2  | {C}              |
```

Sorry for the bad explanation, I'm really lacking the vocabulary here. Any help with writing a query that achieves what's in the example would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
select id, array_agg(some_other_value order by some_other_value ) as values_array from <yourTableName> group by id
```

You can also check [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Answer (score 1):

See [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html) documentation.

```
SELECT
    id,
    array_agg(some_other_value)
FROM
    the_table
GROUP BY
    id;
```